# Is there an OS wide manner for opting out of display advertisements on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I am running the enterprise evaluation version of Windows 8 and wonder if I missed a setup step to opt out of the advertisements in some of the tiles like the one below.

[image]

I have not yet turned on location services and am less worried about tracking at this moment than just not seeing the ads as I explore the OS. I'm not looking to ban all advertisement, just the ones that come with the bundled application tiles and the core system.

Did I mistakenly opt-in or enable these? If not, can I disable them system wide in a setting or two (or by hook and crook if necessary)?

Comment: The ads come with Windows 8.... AFAIK, there is no opt out, you did nothing wrong.

Comment: [Its a Feature!](http://hothardware.com/News/Microsofts-Big-Hidden-Windows-8-Feature-BuiltIn-Advertising/)

Comment: @Moab - that "Erase the damage" ad takes on a whole new meaning when you see it in the Finances tile. Reminds me of those diners where "featured" means we're going to throw it out tomorrow, so sell all you can today.

Comment: I don't see the ads!

Comment: I believe that host-blocking Microsoft's AD server will suffice, except if it's added to the Windows's bypass-host-list for a given list of domains (sorry, no references available now)

Comment: The real problem is getting to know its hostname. I couldn't decompile their DLLs successfully so far. I'll try tcpdump or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it currently stands, there's no way to opt-out of the ads.  The ["Ads in Apps" framework](http://advertising.microsoft.com/ads-in-apps) is provided by Microsoft to App creators as a unified advertising system to make monetizing their programs easier (and probably so MS gets a cut as well).

Just because the apps may have been bundled with Windows, doesn't mean the app creators don't (also) want to get paid by advertisements. :)

The assumption is that the ads are paying for the service that the App is using to give you information, not for paying for the app itself (eg: Weather2Travel.com in your example needs to keep their servers up to make the app useful).

Looking into my crystal ball:  Will someone eventually figure out how to block them?  Probably.  Will MS change the framework so that the blocks don't work anymore?  Probably.   Will this be an endless battle?  Probably. ;)

Comment: Hmm - it does seem to be integrated with tiles like Finance (where **GAIN** detergent can apparently help with a positive name and restorative cleansing if your finances were battered today), Travel in addition to Weather. It seems a bit odd to bundle ads with an OS that asks so nicely if you want do-not-track but I suppose making money is the goal of most companies.

Comment: Making money/profits is the goal of ALL companies. :)

Comment: Let us all take a moment to thank Microsoft for adding this brilliant and innovative feature.

Comment: So what happens when a Metro app with ads is snapped to 1/3rd of the screen? Does it waste space even in that small view? If so, IMO MS might have just ruined snap mode completely and shot themselves in the foot. At least they could have left them out of apps installed by default in genuine paid copies of the OS.

Comment: You'd stop using that app and go get a different one that isn't as annoying.  :)

Comment: @Karan I decided to uninstall them all apart Photos and live with the Desktop only

Answer (score 0):

Block the following DNSes

```
mobileads.msn.com
ads1.msads.net
*.msads.net
```

The last two are likely to be the guilty ones. Windows 8 features a hosts file protection via Windows Defender that must be disabled first

This worked fine for a number of apps I have tried so far. It has not been tested for "any" app and in the future it can stop working.

Comment: Don't know what you're referring to in your last sentence. WinRT does have a desktop and file permissions.

Comment: @Karan I preferred to remove my last sentence. While I read an article about ad blocking not working in Windows RT 1) I can't find references about it right now and 2) the method of blocking hosts is not tested and not yet supposed to be ineffective. Thanks for pointing out.