# How to block ads in win 8 metro apps (e.g., Bing ad)

Tags: windows-8, adblock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an OS wide manner for opting out of display advertisements on Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/503591/is-there-an-os-wide-manner-for-opting-out-of-display-advertisements-on-windows-8)

If a child plays a game in windows 8, some games have ads from most likely Microsoft ad framework. Is there a hack how to block the jpg of some of the ads (e.g., Bing search ad). Something like an ad blocker in Android.

Comment: Agreed. I even installed Windows 8 Parental Controls and block everything except specific things that I specify. The Apps still flash advertisements at my children.

Comment: No idea if it's feasible, but couldn't one just check from which server the ads are retrieved and block it via the hosts file?